# Can't install/enable debugger on Win 10 and Python 3.9.2?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to enable debugger extension on Win 10, with Python 3.9.2 but the kernel refuse to install.
[image]

[image]

Please advise how to solve it and enable the debugger.

Comment: what version is your pip

Comment: @BijayRegmi my pip version is 21.0.1

Comment: try downloading wheel files and installing it locally with pip : https://pypi.org/project/xeus-python/0.12.1/#files , it works flawlessly on my end iwth python3.9

Comment: @BijayRegmi I have seen there is no wheel for Windows and Python 3.9.
I will wait for it.